# Создание библиотек классов C# в vs code

Tags: c#

Можно ли в vs code создать библиотеку классов, гугл дает ответ только в Visual Studio. Извиняюсь за глупый вопрос.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new?tabs=netcore22

Comment: `dotnet new classlib` в нужной папке

Comment: @ヒミコ большое спасибо!

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, Это конечно правильно, но пусть ТС прочитает про доступные параметры, дабы в дальнейшем не возникало вопросов.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko Вам тоже спасибо, но я сам уже с источником разобрался :)